# Auto change order status from processing to Preparing in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Auto change order status from processing to Preparing in Woocommerce 1 day after placing order.

Auto change order status from processing to Preparing in Woocommerce 1 day after placing order.

Comment: Try using cron Job and Hooks. Follow this link [link](https://wordpress-trickz.blogspot.com/2016/06/create-cron-in-wordpress-with-custom.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'wp_orders');
function wp_orders()
{
    global $wpdb;
       $my_query = "SELECT * FROM wp_wc_order_stats where STATUS='wc-processing'";
        $val123 = $wpdb->get_row($my_query, OBJECT);
        $result2 = $wpdb->get_results($my_query);
        foreach ($result2 as $results2) {

            $date1 = $results2->date_created_gmt;
            $order_id = $results2->order_id;

            $date2=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

            $dteStart = new DateTime($date1);
            $dteEnd   = new DateTime($date2);
            $dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
            $Diff = $dteDiff->format("%d");
            $int = (int)$Diff;
            if($int>1)
            {
                $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
                if (!empty($order)) {

               // change your status to wc-preparing

                    $order->update_status( 'wc-preparing' );
                }
            }
        }
}
```

You can set this function in the cron job too in your Cpanel.

Comment: Thanks   How can i skip sunday

Comment: ````if(in_array(date('D'),['Sun'])) {
return;
}````

Add this condition before loop

Comment: Hi,

 i have added the above code but it not working for me i think something went wrong, still showing in processing only

Comment: add_action('init', 'wp_orders');
function wp_orders()
{
    global $wpdb;
       $my_query = "SELECT * FROM wp_wc_order_stats where STATUS='wc-processing'";
        $val123 = $wpdb->get_row($my_query, OBJECT);
        $result2 = $wpdb->get_results($my_query);

Comment: foreach ($result2 as $results2) {

            $date1 = $results2->date_created_gmt;
            $order_id = $results2->order_id;

            $date2=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

            $dteStart = new DateTime($date1);
            $dteEnd   = new DateTime($date2);
            $dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
            $Diff = $dteDiff->format("%d");
            $int = (int)$Diff;
            if($int>1)
{
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
if (!empty($order)) {
$order->update_status( 'wc-accepted' );
}
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init', 'change_order_status');
    function change_order_status() {
        global $wpdb;

        // Query for orders with a status of "wc-processing"
        $my_query = "SELECT * FROM wp_wc_order_stats WHERE STATUS='wc-processing'";
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($my_query);

        // Iterate through the results
        foreach ($result as $order) {
            $order_id = $order->order_id;
            $order_date = $order->date_created_gmt;

            // Get the current date
            $current_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

            // Calculate the difference in days between the order date and the current date
            $dteStart = new DateTime($order_date);
            $dteEnd = new DateTime($current_date);
            $dteDiff = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
            $diff_in_days = $dteDiff->format("%d");

            // Compare the difference in days to 1
            if ($diff_in_days >= 1) {
                $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
                if (!empty($order)) {
                    // Change the order status to "wc-accepted"
                    $order->update_status('wc-accepted');
                }
            }
        }
        // Query for orders with a status of "wc-accepted"
        $my_query = "SELECT * FROM wp_wc_order_stats WHERE STATUS='wc-accepted'";
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($my_query);

        // Iterate through the results
        foreach ($result as $order) {
            $order_id = $order->order_id;
            $order_date = $order->date_created_gmt;

            // Get the current date
            $current_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

            // Calculate the difference in days between the order date and the current date
            $dteStart = new DateTime($order_date);
            $dteEnd = new DateTime($current_date);
            $dteDiff = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
            $diff_in_days = $dteDiff->format("%d");

            // Compare the difference in days to 5
            if ($diff_in_days >= 5) {
                $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
                if (!empty($order)) {
                    // Change the order status to "wc-preparing"
                    $order->update_status('wc-preparing');
                }
            }
        }
        // Query for orders with a status of "wc-preparing"
        $my_query = "SELECT * FROM wp_wc_order_stats WHERE STATUS='wc-preparing'";
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($my_query);
        // Iterate through the results
        foreach ($result as $order) {
            $order_id = $order->order_id;
            $order_date = $order->date_created_gmt;

            // Get the current date
            $current_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

            // Calculate the difference in days between the order date and the current date
            $dteStart = new DateTime($order_date);
            $dteEnd = new DateTime($current_date);
            $dteDiff = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
            $diff_in_days = $dteDiff->format("%d");

            // Compare the difference in days to 6
            if ($diff_in_days >= 6) {
                $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
                if (!empty($order)) {
                    // Change the order status to "wc-ready-to-ship"
                    $order->update_status('wc-ready-to-ship');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).